# Kotlin - Replace a single two-methods interface with two different one-method interfaces

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

First of all, I want to clarify that my questions is for a personal code-style preference.

Let's say I have a method which takes an interface as parameter, and the said interface has two methods in it.

In kotlin, implementing the interface anonymously, we would have something like

```
client.execute(object : Callback() {
    override fun onResponse(response: Response) {/*...*/}
    override fun onError(error: Error) {/*...*/}
})
```

What I would like to do is to create an extensions for the `client` object that would take two different interfaces such as

```
interface ClientResponse{fun onResponse(response: Response)}
interface ClientError{fun onError(error: Error)}
```

and then the new `execute` method would look like

```
client.executeCustom(
    {response -> /*...*/},
    {error -> /*...*/}
})
```

so kind of a SAM solution.

Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a fairly trivial extension to write, you can just take two lambda parameters immediately, and then create a `Callback` instance inside that delegates calls to those lambdas:

```
fun Client.executeCustom(onResponse: (Response) -> Unit, onError: (Error) -> Unit) {
    execute(object : Callback() {
        override fun onResponse(response: Response) = onResponse(response)
        override fun onError(error: Error) = onError(error)
    })
}
```

This way, you don't even need to introduce new interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!